# Animation rotation of an object around another boject's fixed vertices

Tags: modeling, animation, vertices, edges

I have this landing gear bay doors that I am trying to animate with a simple rotation to open at a 90-degree angle.  The bay doors are a separate object from the plane. The pivot point is where the 3d cursor is.

[image]

However, when the rotation takes place the main vertices and edge of the landing bay doors are totally off from the ones on the plane they should rotate around.

[image]

Is it possible to make the bay door rotate around the vertices and edge between them as indicated in red in the first photo?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
It helps to be aware of a couple of things.

1. You can rotate an object around one of the 3 main world axies, by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> and then either <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>.
2. You can rotate an object around one of its 3 **internal** axies, by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> and then either <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> **twice**. (if you tilted an object a bit the world axies and the internal axis no longer align)
3. In order to rotate your bay door object around the red highlighted edge, you have to place the origin (a pivot) somewhere on this edge **and** align this edge with one of the 6 aforementioned axis and then make this orientation it's normal state, so to say, by applying the rotation.

So select your door in the 3D viewport, rotate it in a way so the red edge is parallel to a world axis (the X-axis for instance). Then (also in the 3D viewport) go to Object > Apply > Rotation.

Lastly rotate and move it back into its place on the plane. Now if you press <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> twice, the door should rotate around the red edge.