Rotating an object on a tilted axis
Afternoon folks,
Lets see if I can explain this in a way that makes sense.
I need these hatches to open outwards 90 degrees;

The problem seems to arise from the fact the surface they're attached to is sloped downwards slightly;

This causes rotations to look like this. Sometimes hitting Y twice will help with this, but not this time.

Is there an easy way to get this to rotate properly relative to the slope under it so that it comes out more like this;

PS; I need to animate it to pop open and the PDC under it to deploy up, so I need it to be able to rotate those 90 degrees smoothly if at all possible.
Update: The idea from the comments works, kind of, though I'm not sure WHY.
This works when I keyframe it out manually - turning from 0 to 90 degrees works fine by hand. When the animation plays it still flicks one end on one door out a bit. Not sure why, the other door animates fine. xD

I use the closed picture above as the first keyframe, then this one below as the second 15 frames later. This looks fine and is where I want it to be. If I use R and Yx2 then 90 - it pivots perfectly. I can mouse it backwards and forwards just fine as well.

But if I play the animation the bottom door flicks the bottom out a bit. The top door opens fine.

I apologize for not understanding something that is probably really simple, Ive done very little animation before today :D

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199397/animation-rotation-of-an-object-around-another-bojects-fixed-vertices/199418#199418 and many others if you care to search for them!

@JohnEason To me this seems to be more a question about custom orientations and parenting...

@GordonBrinkmann That seemed to be the most relevant answer from the long list that popped up when I did a search here. Many of the others are about windmill and electron rotation.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill/129836 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283234/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-another-objects-local-axis

Didn't understand the skybox answer at all ( I'm a bit slow and still not real good ) but the ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199397/animation-rotation-of-an-object-around-another-bojects-fixed-vertices/199418#199418 ) gave me an idea. I made a new plane, used snap to rotation to get the angle right then boolean modifier the shape so it fills the hole neatly, the solidified it. Now it has both local and global XYZ axis and lets me rotate it neatly. Which SEEMS to be working. I'll need to test it a bit more.

The problems with the other answers linked to here is that they usually talk about using or aligning to another object's axes - which you don't have. You have to create that orientation from what you have. Maybe my answer can help... it looks longer and more complicated than it is, I just wanted to make sure there is no step unclear (hope I did).

About your edit: to understand what is going wrong with the bottom hatch we would need to see how you actually did it, only knowing that you followed the suggestions and assuming how exactly you followed those examples is a bit useless.

The best approach for these kinds of things is having an empty which provides the orientation as frame of reference for the hatch door to keep the rotation on a single axis. This empty should have one axis aligned with the desired axis of rotation. To get it aligned, you can do the following:
Here I have an object which has almost all sides not aligning with the global axes. The same goes for the two hatches, apart from that all objects have their origin at the world center.

Now looking at one of the hatches itself, I would imagine they have some kind of hinge going through the center of the marked faces (on the left), which would mean I want the object's transform pivot point i.e. its origin centered between them and the transform orientation should have one of its axes aligned with this hinge (right side).

To achieve this, you do not need to create a hinge object like I did for visualization. First, let's set the origin of the hatch to this desired center. Select both faces in Edit Mode, then from the Mesh menu choose Snap > Origin to Selected and Cursor to Selected (because we need the cursor there later).

Now you need to align the transform orientation. To do this, select an edge or two vertices for example which are parallel to the rotation axis you want the hatch to rotate along. The two faces selected before might work or not, it depends a lot on the geometry and how this is oriented. So the easiest way would be if you knew for sure they are aligned the way you need. It is not even necessary to choose them from the hatch, if they are from the surrounding object it would be okay too.

I chose the edge along the center between the two hatches (the yellow one above). Then I open the drop-down menu of the Transform Orientation and click the + button to add a new custom orientation. By default this will be called "Edge" or "Vertex" depending on what you have selected.

Switch back to Object Mode and add an Empty. It should be placed at the origin of the hatch if you correctly placed the 3D cursor there earlier. Now make sure the Transform Orientation is set to "Edge" or whatever the custom orientation is called. Usually it is selected by default after you added it. Then with the Empty still selected, go to Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation.

The Empty is now aligned with the custom orientation, in my case this means the Y axis is aligned with the desired rotation axis. Now select the hatch, then Shift select the Empty and press Ctrl+P to parent the hatch to the empty. Important: choose the option Set Parent to > Object (Keep Transform Without Inverse).

After this is done, select only the hatch and press Ctrl+A > Apply > Rotation. This resets all rotation angles on the hatch to 0° relative to the parent object. So no matter how you rotate the parent now, the hatch will have all local rotation values 0°.

And this is now how you can rotate the hatch on the Y axis without the need to rotate along any other axis. Here I animated the Y angle from 0° to 90° and back:

The Empty's rotation might be a bit weird apart from the Y axis being aligned. People often choose a face to have the Z axis for example pointing "upwards" from the face. However you have to be careful when choosing faces, the Z might be pointing in a preferable direction, but depending on how the outline of the face is designed (in my case it is an n-gon with those "hinge connectors" on the side), neither X nor Y might be aligned with the rotation axis afterwards. So I prefer specific edges or vertices if I only need to get one axis aligned.
In my example, as mentioned earlier you don't have to select a part of the hatch for the orientation, as long as it provides the correct orientation for at least one axis to be aligned with the rotation axis. But here I could have chosen a face of the main object for example, it is a simple quad, the long edges are parallel the rotation axis and the short edges are perpendicular to it. This allows the custom orientation to be aligned correctly:

Another tip: if you have set up the second hatch like the first, you only need to animate one of them (if they should move synchronously). The second can be driven by the first one with a Copy Rotation constraint like this:
Select the second hatch and give it a Copy Location constraint. As Target you choose the first hatch, for Axis you choose Y since this is the one that the first hatch rotates around, and for Invert I choose Y as well since I found out that the second hatch rotates in the opposite direction (it does not have to be like that, depends on the custom orientations and the empties etc.). Another important thing is to set Target and Owner to Local Space.

For animating the hatch rotations with the help of a controller object, see my answer to this question: Rigging Landing Gear or you can also watch the tutorial in which @RyanKingArt used the result from that answer: How I Created this Supermarine Spitfire 3d Model in Blender at around 27:24

That's perfect. TYSM for taking the time. :) - One question : Could another axis be set to the controller as well as the Y? For instance an off-set Z axis so the doors could be opened 90 degrees and then slid down out of the way? ( You know, just to make this even more complicated for my smooth brain. ;)

@CynicalKiwi With controller you mean a controller object like in the other answer? Sure, you can add several constraints and use different target objects for them. It's all just a matter of knowing what you want and finding the best way to do it.

Cheers mate, I think I got it working how I want. I used a face as the orientation for the controller, which has given it nicely aligned up/down/left/right relative to the object so I can now pop the doors open and slide them neatly down out of the way. The Copy Location is excellent too, I've only had to animate it once. TY so much for the help, it's really much appreciated. :)
